# Simulation Class Design

Tags: c++, oop

I'm looking to do simulations with very complicated initial conditions from the user. I'm writing `class A` whose member variables need to be initialized by the user before running `A.Solve()` to get the results stored in a file. The initialization is rather complicated and requires several temporary data structures that will no longer be needed after the initialization. So, I wrote another class called `class Initializer` which stores a reference to an object of `class A`. My code will look like this:

```
 class A {
   friend class Initializer;
   private:
     // member variables storing the state of the system
   public:
     void Solve();
     ...
 };

 class Initializer {
   private:
     A& a
     // Other data structures used in the initialization
     ...
   public:
     // functions called by the user to set up for the initialization
     ...
     Initialize(); // after this is called, a will be ready to solve
 };

 int main(...) {
   A a;
   Initializer init(a);
   // call functions on init to initialize the system
   ...
   init.Initialize();
   a.Solve();
   return 0;
 }
```

But it seems like data structures in `init` will live on the stack for the entire program. To prevent that, is it ok to do this:

```
  A a;
  Initializer *init = new Initializer(a);
  ....
  init.Initialize();
  delete init;
  a.Solve();
```

Or does this look unnecessary and should I just have everything contained in `class A`?

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here.  It depends on a lot of things.  The only reason to create an "initializer" class(given the simplified context of the question) for this data, from my point of view, would be to keep it around in the event you had to create many versions of class a, so you could release instances of class a, and maintain it's configuration data.  Otherwise, it seems to me to be an unnecessary layer of abstraction.  But again, this opinion is formed on very limited scope of information.

Comment: I agree with @ChrisCM. Unnecessary layer of abstraction if you only have 1 `A` to initialize. As for deallocating `Initializer` after `init.Initialize()`, dynamic allocation via `new/delete` will work. You can also wrap `Initializer init(a); ...; init.Initialize()` in a block of `{}`, or you can move `Initializer init(a); ...; init.Initialize()` into some function `doIniti(a)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your original line of thought, the usual solution is to restrict the scope of the `init` variable:

```
A a;
{
    Initializer init(a);
    //...
} // init is destroyed as soon as the scope exits
a.Solve();
```

---

Your `new/delete` variant is quite brittle and will leak memory if anything throws between `new` and `delete`. To fix that, use smart pointers:

```
A a;
std::unique_ptr<Initializer> init(new Initializer(a));
//...
init.reset();
a.Solve();
```

---

However as others have said, this whole design is kinda weird and probably overkill. If the initialization is really so complicated that you can't get away with constructors then you may want to do it the other way around: instead of `Initializer` taking an argument `A` and operating on it, you should pass a fully ready-to-use `Initializer` to `A`'s constructor, which will in turn either copy the whole `Initializer` to keep a copy of the data, or just copy the relevant bits. `Initializer` should then probably be renamed to `Config` or something like that. Notice how a `Config/Initializer` object can now be reused to initialize several `A` objects, and even be modified between two `A` initializations.

Unfortunately this is hard to give you definitive advice with so little information.

**Note:** if you use C++11 you may be interested in [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) which enables the new brace-initialization syntax. Depending on the complexity of your data it may involve more work than your current solution but you'll end up with a very nice and intuitive syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Here, using another class for initialization purpose seem to be overkill.

Just initialize in class A constructor.
Once the constructor execution completes, the temporary data structures will be freed automatically.